# RxJava filter operator

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I am new in rxJava.

Well, I was testing few examples to integrate operators in rxJava.
So, I have a problem with this:

```
    Observable.just("JUAN", "LUCILA", "ARMANDO").map(new Function<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(String s) throws Exception {
            return s.length();
        }
    }).all(new Predicate<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Integer integer) throws Exception {
            return integer > 0;
        }
    }).filter(new Predicate<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
            return aBoolean;
        }
    }).subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Boolean value) {
            Log.d("STATUS: ", "OK");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d("STATUS: ", "COMPLETE");
        }
    })
```

So, AndroidStudio marks me error on subscribe(new Observer).
My objective is transform the names to a number by the length, so with all I hope make a condition, obviously it will be true, and late, filter that TRUE, from filter, and next show me a log message saying OK!

I hope that you can help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Single` at http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/

As said in the comment `Observable.all(...)` you have type `Single` then from `Single.filter(...)` you have type `Maybe`.

So use you need `toObservable()` and then subscribe.

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final Maybe<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(predicate, "predicate is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new MaybeFilterSingle<T>(this, predicate));
}
```

`

Change to

```
Observable.just("JUAN", "LUCILA", "ARMANDO").map(new Function<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(String s) throws Exception {
                return s.length();
            }
        }).all(new Predicate<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                return integer > 0;
            }
        }).filter(new Predicate<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                return aBoolean;
            }
        }).toObservable().subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Boolean value) {
                Log.d("STATUS: ", "OK");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d("STATUS: ", "COMPLETE");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I believe the type changes to `Single` at `Observable.all(...)`, then to `Maybe` at `Single.filter(...)`. Since `Observable.filter(...)` returns `Observable`.

Comment: @Kiskae yes its is according to the source